# Powerpoint crashes far too frequently

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

A user of mine does a lot of work in Powerpoint 2007. She frequently has several instances open, but we've experienced the same issue with only one instance open. She'll be working in Powerpoint and it will crash. Below is the crash report:

> Problem signature:
>     Problem Event Name:                        APPCRASH
>     Application Name:                             POWERPNT.EXE
>     Application Version:                           12.0.4518.1014
>     Application Timestamp:                    45428035
>     Fault Module Name:                          kernel32.dll
>     Fault Module Version:                        6.0.6002.18005
>     Fault Module Timestamp:                 49e038c0
>     Exception Code:                                  e0000002
>     Exception Offset:                                0001e124
>     OS Version:                                          6.0.6002.2.2.0.16.7
>     Locale ID:                                             1033
>
> Additional information about the problem:
>     LCID:                                                     1033
>     Brand:                                                   Office12Crash
>     skulcid:                                                 1033

If anyone provide a link how to properly capture a DMP, I'll be happy to record one.

Her PC is running Windows Vista Professional 64-bit. It's got an Intel Core Duo 2.4GHz, and 4GB RAM. We've repeated the same issue on a Server 2008 Terminal Server with over 10GB RAM.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are any VBA macros being used when this happens? On my last co-op I had to develop applications in VBA and occasionally something would happen where they would the program would just start crashing Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that this hotfix tends to improve the situation. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975021

Answer (score 1):

According to the article ["Diagnose and repair crashing Office programs by using Office Diagnostics"](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA012340761033.aspx), you can run these tests by:

1. Click the Microsoft Office ButtonButton image, and then click PowerPoint Options.
2. Click Resources.
3. Click Diagnose, click Continue, and then click Start Diagnostics.

Apart for this, are there any common properties between the two crashing machines, such as maybe same model of installed printer?

Comment: Printer redirection is enabled on the terminal services box. I can try disabling it.