# Powerpoint 2010 crash on quickstyle menu

Tags: windows-7, crash, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-powerpoint

Windows 7 64-bit, recent install, added Office 2010.

When I create some boxes and open the quick-style menu, it crashes (or stops responding, in windowese, and then it sends an error report).

- I've run the "Repair" from the installer, but it didn't help.
- There's nothing in Windows Update
- I've Googled and searched on Microsoft's site, but n

Any other ideas?

(It's not related to [this ppt crash question](https://superuser.com/questions/49619/powerpoint-crashes-far-too-frequently) as that concerns PPT 2007.

Error in event log:

```
Faulting application name: POWERPNT.EXE, version: 14.0.4754.1000, time stamp: 0x4b967cf2
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdfe0
Exception code: 0xe0000003
Fault offset: 0x000000000000aa7d
Faulting process id: 0xee8
Faulting application start time: 0x01cb9dc710fd76d8
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\POWERPNT.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 58766562-09ba-11e0-90d1-00215a139192
```

And:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: POWERPNT.EXE
P2: 14.0.4754.1000
P3: 4b967cf2
P4: KERNELBASE.dll
P5: 6.1.7600.16385
P6: 4a5bdfe0
P7: e0000003
P8: 000000000000aa7d
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\marcusl\AppData\Local\Temp\CVR86DD.tmp.cvr
C:\Users\marcusl\AppData\Local\Temp\WERC765.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\marcusl\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_POWERPNT.EXE_d45f313d77f7e52cc8682b2b64cc3898127c2c_1106e3ac

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 58766562-09ba-11e0-90d1-00215a139192
Report Status: 1
```

Comment: Any critical or warning items in the application or system portions of the event viewer? Are you using an OpenGL driver for your video card?

Comment: Yup. Using NVIDIA GTX 260 card. I'll update the driver and see if it helps.

Comment: Didn't help. :(